# Django Auth Issues

Tags: python, django

Ive been configuring and troubleshooting some Django auth issues with a custom backend.
One thing I have noticed is that once the expiry date has expired for the session (confirmed via a Session.objects.all()) that the session remains in the table.

At the point that I have to reauthenticate it creates another entry creating a situation where a single user can have tons of sessions within the table rather then just one.
Is there a simple way of getting Django to clear these out at the point of them expiring ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#clearing-the-session-store) -

> Django does not provide automatic purging of expired sessions. Therefore, it’s your job to purge expired sessions on a regular basis. Django provides a clean-up management command for this purpose: clearsessions. It’s recommended to call this command on a regular basis, for example as a daily cron job.

Use something like this:
`python manage.py clearsessions`

...and schedule it to run regularly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear everything in the session:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
def clear_session(request):
     request.session.flush()
```

If you want to clear particular key:

```
def clear_specific_key(request, key):
  del request.session[key]
```